# How to add <br> in file_put_contents?

Tags: php

A simple question, But I could not find a solution

```
$file = 'file.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "$time|$data<br>", FILE_APPEND);
```

file right now, after 2 times in loop:

```
03-24-2018|test03-24-2018|test
```

I need:

```
03-24-2018|test
03-24-2018|test
```

Comment: Instead `<br>` try `\n`.

Comment: Your code produce `03-24-2018|test<br>03-24-2018|test<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';

file_put_contents($file, "$time|$data\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [predefined `PHP_EOL` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol), new line characters are different depends on operating systems:

Windows: `\r\n`

Mac OS: `\r`

Unix-like systems: `\n`

```
$content = "$time|$data" . PHP_EOL;
```